# Strange Issue with RowBox

Tags: notebooks, wolfram-cloud

Can someone explain why this notebook [[RANGEWORKING.nb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3i4M7rrJuUVWHgzX1ZYS21VYVU/view?usp=sharing)]

```
Notebook[{
  Cell[
    BoxData[
      RowBox[{"Range", "[", RowBox[{"0", ",", "\n", "3"}], "]"}]     
    ],"Input"
  ]
}]
```

allows me execute the input cell in Mathematica Desktop while this notebook [[RANGEBROKEN.nb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3i4M7rrJuUVMnRnUFhBbE5IRE0/view?usp=sharing)]

```
Notebook[{
  Cell[
    BoxData[
      RowBox[{"Range[0,","\n","3]"}]
    ],"Input"
  ]
}]
```

does not allow me to execute the input cell in Mathematica Desktop? I am opening these notebooks in Version 10.

The reason I am asking this is because I encountered this issue when I downloaded a file created in the Wolfram Programming Cloud.

To create RANGEBROKEN.nb:

1. Created a new file in the Wolfram Programming Cloud named RANGEBROKEN.nb
2. Created a new cell by typing `Range[0,`
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Typed `3]`
5. Downloaded the notebook and stripped some unnecessary arguments to make a minimal example.

To create RANGEWORKING.nb:

1. Created a new file in Mathematica Desktop named RANGEWORKING.nb
2. Created a new cell by typing `Range[0,`
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Typed `3]`
5. Stripped some unnecessary arguments to make a minimal example.
6. Replaced `\[IndentingNewLine]` with `\n`

You can see I went through the same process to create the content in the file in the cloud versus the desktop, but the cloud version is somehow "broken."

Comment: This `Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"Range", "[", "0", ",", "\n", "3", "]"}]],"Input"]}] `still gives a good result, but this: `Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"Range[", "0", ",", "\n", "3", "]"}]],"Input"]}] `does not. The problem arises as soon as one includes the first bracket between the quotations. I do not understand, why though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a reproducible bug. I submitted a ticket to Wolfram and I received a response that they will look in to it:

> Hello -
>
> Thank you for your email.
>
> I have reproduced this problem with downloading files from the Wolfram
>   Cloud and report the problem to our developers.  This may allow them
>   to fix the problem in the future.
>
> Please let me know if you have any further questions.
>
> Karl Isensee
>
> Technical Support